# LD_PRELOAD or similar to warn user about modifications to a file?

Tags: filesystems, access-control

I am running a (complex) script that seems to modify at some point a file. I would like to get warnings whenever the script / program tries to write, chmod, chown or perform any other attempt that I disapprove of. I want the program to have normal access to the rest of the filesystem.

Denying access is one solution, but since I have to run the script as root, it won't work. The script could override any access control settings. Even if I could run the script as non-root, the script could decide to take a different branch on access failure. That's why I prefer a warning-on-access instead of an access denial. Is there a solution (e.g. SE Linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this:

#### auditd

use the following command to enable auditd monitoring of the file (after making sure the `auditd` service is running):

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F path=/path/to/file
```

Then look in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to see what's going on.

Use the following to remove the rule when done:

```
auditctl -d exit,always -F path=/path/to/file
```

#### fanotify

fanotify is a system designed for things like virus scanners. It allows a program to receive an event notification when another program opens any file. The monitor program can then perform actions like denying access to the file, or merely logging it. The advantage here is that **the monitoring program can simply sit on the event and do nothing, so the program which is trying to open the file just delays**. It won't get a failure or a success until the monitor program allows it to continue.

The problem with this route though is that fanotify is new, and there aren't any simple command line utilities that you can use to access it. You would have to write your own script (if any scripting libraries have an interface) or program.

Comment: fanotify with its "sit on the event" feature sounds like what I want. I will investigate

Comment: Spoke too soon. fanotify doesn't notice if you edit /tmp/the-file, then mv /tmp/the-file /path/to/the-file. Which is what editors do. https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify/issues/15. I don't if there's any solution.

Comment: That would be a directory operation, because you're not modifying the file, you're modifying the directory the file is in. In fanotify you'd just use `FAN_ONDIR` to watch the directory instead.

Answer (score 2):

If on Linux, `chattr +i the-file` will prevent any modification operation on the file even to `root` (except another `chattr`).

Comment: Works at preventing access, but script seems to take a decision based on failure and carry on. I still can't tell which part of the script tries to write the file.

Answer (score 2):

If your system supports dtrace (Solaris and derivatives, FreeBSD, Oracle Linux, Mac OS X), a dtrace script can log and even prevent the mentioned actions to the files you want by whatever user including root.

Dtrace can also be used to freeze the guilty process and let you make the decision to resume or kill it.

Answer (score 1):

For small scripting jobs where fine grained fs access is needed, but one would prefer to avoid dealing with complicated auditing tools gentoo's "sandbox" utility is exceptionally handy. In particular, it provides an easy way to enable and disable write access to selected files interactively (for test then deploy scenarios).

On Gentoo it's available by default, but should not be too difficult to install on other distros.

http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitweb/?p=proj/sandbox.git;a=summary

Internally it is implemented on top of the LD_PRELOAD mechanism pulling in an "libsandbox.so" library, which intercepts and filters filesystem calls. It also comes with neat interactive shell wrapper, so one only needs to type "sandbox" to drop into protected shell.

The functionality especially asked for by OP (fake writes) is supported:
http://devmanual.gentoo.org/function-reference/sandbox-functions/index.html